# Intellisense doesn't work after piping from custom cmdlet (Powershell ISE)

Tags: powershell

If I type the following line in the PowerShell ISE editor, I get Intellisense after the dot operator in `$_` variable:

```
Get-ChildItem ATextFile.txt | foreach { $_.FullName }
```

In this case, `$_` is an instance of `System.IO.FileSystemInfo`. The editor will properly list all accessible members from this object.

Now, if I write:

```
function GetFile {
  return [System.IO.FileInfo]::new(".\ATextFile.txt")
}

GetFile | foreach { $_.FullName }
```

The script runs fine, but Intellisense doesn't work after the dot operator in `$_`.

Am I missing a syntax to make IntelliSense work correctly? Maybe an annotation to "document" the returning value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the `OutputType` attribute above the *Param* section:

```
function GetFile {
    [OutputType([System.IO.FileInfo])]
    Param(

    )

  return [System.IO.FileInfo]::new(".\ATextFile.txt")
}
```

---

Please consider to rename your file to reflect *approved verbs*  e. g. `Get-File`. Also note that the `return` statement is not necessary in PowerShell, so your function should look like this:

```
function Get-File 
{
    [OutputType([System.IO.FileInfo])]
    Param
    (
    )

    [System.IO.FileInfo]::new(".\ATextFile.txt")
}
```